# Opel 2.0 CDTI when revved past 2500 rpm won't pull

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, opel, vauxhall, insignia

My 2014 Opel/Vauxhall Insignia 2.0 CDTI with a manual transmission has some acceleration problems in 4th 5th 6th gears.

In those higher gears if I floor the gas pedal, the car will accelerate and pull fine until it reaches ~2500 RPM, and then the engine will instantly rev up to ~3500 or above but won't pull, only if I take my foot off the pedal.
Then the revs drop and pull.
It feels like turbo kicks in at ~2500 and the clutch starts to slip?

If I gradually accelerate without flooring it, I can go over 2500 RPM in any gear and also I can floor it in 1st 2nd 3rd, it won't slip.

Are these all signs of a worn out clutch?

If yes, is it recommended to change the whole kit : clutch, pressure plate, flywheel etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this question I was having the same issues https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/71870/honda-accord-i-dtec-2010-2-2-clutch-recall-problem/71920#71920

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the clutch and, yes, while it is apart do all the bits, but not the flywheel unless it needs it or it is a DMF.