# Honda Accord I-Dtec 2010 2.2 Clutch/Recall problem?

Tags: engine, honda, clutch, accord

Hi I recently bought a Honda Accord Exec 2010 2.2 i-dtec 210k km, I own it for about 5 days now, I have been driving with it everyday, but since yesterday, A weird problem start to occur, When I am accelerating from gear 1-2-3 everything is fine (manual transimmision) but If i go to 4th gear and accelerate from 2000-3000 rpm, The revs are going up but the car does not accelerate, the same happens for gear 5, but gear 6 is back to normal, It looks like a cluth is sleeping but it's fine for lower revs and lower gears, The clutch seems fine, Any one had a this problem previously?? or knows whats the cause?

Comment: If the revs are going up in any gear, the clutch is definitely slipping, get it replaced,

Comment: Why do you think there is a recall?

Comment: Also at 210K km (130K miles) it's very possible the clutch is due for replacement

Comment: The strange thing is that it never happens on gear 1,2,3 and 6 And it also only 'Slips" exactly at 2000rpm to 3000rpm on gear 4 and 5, Could this be the MAF sensor?

Comment: That's when the turbo kicks in

Comment: In a manual transmission vehicle (traditional 3rd pedal manual) there is no way any computer related, sensor related, or engine related issue (with exception of  too much power/torque) can affect the clutch in such a way as to cause it to slip. The clutch is actuated solely by the clutch pedal which either drives a cable or hydraulic cylinder to actuate said clutch. If the vehicle is still stock with no power modifications the only reason for slippage is a worn clutch, bad pressure plate, or something holding the clutch out - like an improperly adjusted cable or pedal.

Comment: So it probably slips when the turbo kicks because at that point the engine starts producing much more power than without the turbo. As to why is only slips on gear 4 & 5, I'm not entirely sure. Is the car able to be moved at all by these gears? Like if you put it into 4 or 5 can you get the car to move at all regardless of clutch slip?

Comment: Another thought here, it could be that since 4 and 5 are higher up in the gears you are applying more throttle without realizing it compared to the lower gears. Since 1, 2, & 3 are easier to "turn" it takes less power to achieve the same acceleration as the higher gears. Also at 6 which is mostly a cruising gear you probably don't accelerate using that gear. Let me know if I'm wrong here but it's a guess. You could also try some full throttle pulls in the lower gears and see if they slip, but it could just affect the higher gears if the clutch is just now starting to go.

Comment: @GabeWisneski Yes, That exactly what happened strangely enough I have solved it by a strange fix a well check my asnwer

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion This was the clutch slipping, I have asked a mechanic friend, about this strange behaviour, He said that sometimes dirt/dust? (I am not very good at this stuff, but I think that's what he meant) builds on the clutch, Thats why the clutch was fine on lower gears and not on higher, He told me to "burn the clutch" a little bit in gear 5,6, Strangely Enough this worked and the clutch does not slip anymore. I have driven 400km since that "fix" and not onces the clutch slipped. He also said that this is very common in Honda Accords.

To be honest I'm still confused on How this have worked but it did, any further explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I just hope it keeps working for you.